# Pyspark - replace null values in column with distinct column value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How do I fill this one column `category` of Nulls with the distinct value in it?

```
+---++--------+----------+
| id||category|      Date|
+---+---------+----------+
| A1|     Null|2010-01-02|
| A1|     Null|2010-01-03|
| A1|    Nixon|2010-01-04|
| A1|     Null|2010-01-05|
| A9|     Null|2010-05-02|
| A9|  Leonard|2010-05-03|
| A9|     Null|2010-05-04|
| A9|     Null|2010-05-05|
+---+---------+----------+
```

**Desired Dataframe:**

```
+---++--------+----------+
| id||category|      Date|
+---+---------+----------+
| A1|    Nixon|2010-01-02|
| A1|    Nixon|2010-01-03|
| A1|    Nixon|2010-01-04|
| A1|    Nixon|2010-01-05|
| A9|  Leonard|2010-05-02|
| A9|  Leonard|2010-05-03|
| A9|  Leonard|2010-05-04|
| A9|  Leonard|2010-05-05|
+---+---------+----------+
```

**I tried:**

```
w = Window().partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Date")
df = df.withColumn("category", F.when(col("category").isNull(), col("category")\
.distinct().over(w))\
.otherwise(col("category")))
```

**I also tried:**

```
df = df.fillna({'category': col('category').distinct()})
```

I have also tried:

```
df = df.withColumn('category', when(df.category.isNull(), df.category.distinct()).otherwise(df.category))
```

Comment: df = df.groupby(['category']).fillna(method='ffill') and the. do a bfill

Comment: This is Pyspark, not Pandas

Comment: if there is only one distinct value for each ID, then just: `df_new = df.withColumn('category', F.first('category',True).over(Window.partitionBy('id')))`

Comment: @jxc, thanks, but this will Null out all of my data

Comment: @Starbucks, the function `first` with the 2nd argument `ignorenulls=True` should pick the first non-NULL value from the same partition. if there is any non-Null values, it should not be all null-out. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first

Comment: I'll read the link you shared shortly. All the continuous variables Null'd out after using that command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first()` with `ignorenulls` parameter as `True`. 
Also, use `rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)` on your window.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import sys

w = Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy("Date")

df.withColumn("new", F.first('category', True).over(w.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)))\
        .orderBy("id", "Date").show()

+---+--------+----------+
| id|category|      Date|
+---+--------+----------+
| A1|   Nixon|2010-01-02|
| A1|   Nixon|2010-01-03|
| A1|   Nixon|2010-01-04|
| A1|   Nixon|2010-01-05|
| A9| Leonard|2010-05-02|
| A9| Leonard|2010-05-03|
| A9| Leonard|2010-05-04|
| A9| Leonard|2010-05-05|
+---+--------+----------+
```